# To send iOS Push Notification ("wake-up" message) through iOS App

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mdm

we are using python mdm server to send commands and policies on iOS devices. APNS sends the wake up notification to get the payload.Can we send wake up call using iOS Application Push notification?Please Help.

Comment: If by "iOS Application Push Notification" you mean a local notification (i.e. not a remote notification) then the answer is yes. Set up a local notification with a time interval or calendar based trigger.

Comment: thanks for reply but can we send notification on demand(whenever some command or payload is send to device i need to wake up device). but not time interval based.In Python we use "    wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('PushCert.pem', False)
    message = APNSNotification()
    message.token(mylocal_DeviceToken)
    message.appendProperty(APNSProperty('mdm', mylocal_PushMagic))
    wrapper.append(message)
    wrapper.notify()" to wake up iOS devices.

Comment: Well, you control when the python script gets run so you can send a notification whenever you want? If the device has network connectivity then it'll get delivered as soon as Apple gets round to passing it on (pretty quickly). If the app is in the background then it gets woken up and you get a little bit of time to deal with the notification in the call back handler.